# File.Copy, An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a program with Windows Forms in C# which sits in the background, and needs to monitor changes to a directory and automatically copy those changes into a target directory. The program will also check for any changes between the two directories on startup and copy those across. Ideally the target directory will be a carbon copy of the base directory while this program is running.

Here is my code.

```
    private const string GamesDirectory = "D:\\Games";
    private const string TestDirectory = "D:\\Test";

    #region Fields

    private readonly Process _launcher;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises an instance of the <see cref="GameReviewManager" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public GameReviewManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _launcher = new Process();
        _launcher.StartInfo.FileName = "GameReviewLauncher";
        _launcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        _launcher.Exited += LauncherExited;
        _launcher.Start();

        MonitorDirectory(TestDirectory);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the launcher exited event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The event.</param>
    private void LauncherExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _launcher.Start();
    }

    private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcherCreated;
        fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcherRenamed;
        fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += FileSystemWatcherDeleted;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        //Now Create all of the directories
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(GamesDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(GamesDirectory, TestDirectory));
        }

        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(GamesDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(GamesDirectory, TestDirectory), false);
        }
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcherRenamed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File renamed: {0}", e.Name);
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcherDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File deleted: {0}", e.Name);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

When I run my program I get this error, An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

It is throwing this error on the first file it tries to change on the second foreach loop in the MonitorDirectory method.

I am not sure what is causing this error. If I delete the contents in the test folder, and then launch the program the error will not occur.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you view the details of the exception in your IDE and paste the contents of the Message property?

Comment: The file 'D:\Test\Gamble.RedBlack.dll' already exists.

Comment: [File.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) throws if the destination file already exists and `overwrite` is set to `false`, as you have set it here.

Comment: So I should do a check if the file exists already?

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite it, then yes. Maybe, check whether the length is the same (or the last modified DateTime is not) and skip it if the copy can be time consuming (different drive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument for `File.Copy()` needs to be `true` to enable it to overwrite a file if it already exists.

```
File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(GamesDirectory, TestDirectory), true);
```